# Hdfs and Hbase: how it works?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, talend

Hi everybody

I'm quite new with bigdata, I have installed a HDFS + Hbase test database and I use Talend Big Data (an ETL) to make my test.

I would like to know : if I put a file directly in the HDFS, without going via hbase, I could never request these data ? I mean, I have to read the entire file if I want to filter data I want to chose, is that right ?

Thanks a lot for any help !

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense to me. pls. refine your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html) is just a distributed file system, you cannot query your files without passing by an intermidiate component.
[Hbase](https://hbase.apache.org/) is a nosql database that persist your data on the HDFS, use it when you need a random access to your data.

If you want to store your files on the HDFS as they are and query them, you can create an external table upon them using [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables).

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for your precise answer, I'm going to have a look at Hive then.

Comment: Done ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use hive on the top of the files which are on the HDFS. You can use bucketing and partitioning in the hive for performance improvement.